# How to calculate storage requirement for neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

We are using Neo4j in our Node.js based application. It stores data coming from remote sensors. And growth rate is exponential. So it's not long that we would be dealing with 10's of millions of nodes and relationships. I am not sure how to calculate storage requirement for this. Is there any formula available which will help in capacity planning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look in the [Neo4j’s Hardware Requirements documentation](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-sizing-and-hardware-calculator). The [Disk Storage section](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-sizing-and-hardware-calculator/#_disk_storage) says that:

> Nodes occupy 15B of space, relationships occupy 31B of space and
>   properties occupy 41B of space.

So, the storage size does not just depend on the number of nodes, but relationships and properties too.

An example disk space calculation (from the docs):

```
10,000    Nodes x 14B = 140kB
1,000,000 Rels  x 33B = 31.5MB
2,010,000 Props x 41B = 78.6MB

Total  is 110.2MB
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno. I think i missed this part where it had space for each components. I will go through and it try to calculate storage for the data we have.

Comment: Hi @SwapnilB you are welcome! If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Sure. I thought I missed it before. thanks for pointing out :)